# OSX API CTFontDrawGlyphs() does not return correct alpha values for AppleColorEmoji glyphs

Tags: macos, text, fonts, alpha, emoji

I'm using CTFontDrawGlyphs() API to render glyphs from the AppleColorEmoji font. I've used the following information to create the CGContext :
RGB, 32 bpp, 8 bpc, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst

The actual png files in the 'sbix' table of the AppleColorEmoji font contain proper alpha values. The background of the emojis are transparent while the foreground is opaque. But when rendered using the CTFontDrawGlyphs API the alpha channel of the rendered glyph contains all 0xFF values resulting in an completely opaque square rendition. As a result of missing alpha values, I'm not being able to blend it correctly with a colored background.

Is this a known limitation of the API ? Am I doing something wrong while creating the context which is resulting in this unexpected behavior ? Please help.

Comment: Did you find the answer to it? I have same question.

Comment: Yes. I'd raised a case with Apple. Please see the answer.

Comment: I'll try the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `CTFontDrawGlyphs()` does not write semi-transparent alpha values in the context buffer if you have filled the bytes of the context buffer with `0xFF` values.

As suggested by Apple developer support, I did the a memset of the buffer that I'm passing to the context with `0x00` values. After this, `CTFontDrawGlyphs()` started writing the alpha values properly even for semi-transparent pixels.